Visual Studio Code keeps loading with no code showing
I am experiencing this issue where my Visual Studio Code is loading for a long time with no code showing. Does anybody knows how to fix this issue and what causes this?
I have tried restarting and shutting down but it is still not working.
I am on MacOS


whats your vscode version?

@jamj Version: 1.95.3

whats mac versions?
